# Как сделать экспорт функции MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

в phpMyAdmin жму экспорт, появляется окошко со скриптом

```
CREATE DEFINER=`srv53642_r`@`%`
FUNCTION `translit_func`(`_txt` VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE _f varchar(5);
    DECLARE _t varchar(15);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT f,t from translit;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    open cur;
  the_loop: LOOP

    #get the values of each column into our variables
    FETCH cur INTO _f,_t;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    set _txt=replace(_txt,_f,_t);   
  END LOOP the_loop;

  CLOSE cur;
  return _txt;
END
```

Запускаю этот скрипт не работает!

> ошибка - "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3 "

Comment: не уверен, но осмелюсь предположить что надо установить delimiter

Comment: добавил delimiter, ошибка другая, но функция создалась )

Comment: а куда ж она денется :)

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что тело хранимой функции содержит множество выражений, завершающихся точкой с запятой. Поэтому использовать ее в конце запроса не получится - анализатор не сможет понять, какая из точек с запятой является завершающей. Поэтому при создании хранимых процедур и функций признак окончания запроса обычно меняют. В консоли это можно сделать при помощи команды `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`srv53642_r`@`%`
FUNCTION `translit_func`(`_txt` VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE _f varchar(5);
    DECLARE _t varchar(15);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT f,t from translit;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    open cur;
  the_loop: LOOP

    #get the values of each column into our variables
    FETCH cur INTO _f,_t;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    set _txt=replace(_txt,_f,_t);   
  END LOOP the_loop;

  CLOSE cur;
  return _txt;
END//
```

В phpMyAdmin для этого предназначено специальное текстовое поле "Разделитель", расположенное чуть ниже текстовой области в которой размещается SQL-запрос.